# Помогите связать мой django с mysql

Tags: mysql, python, django, nginx, uwsgi

Связка nginx + uwsgi + python(django) + virtualenv. Пытаюсь поставить mysql вместо sqlite
Кусок моего конфига:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'butlers',
        'USER': 'butlers',
        'PASSWORD': 'm6XWWG29XzGe',
    }
}
```

Кажется всё что мог Я уже сделал. Облазил кучу всего, но не могу понять в чём проблема. Все утилиты под мускуль ставил из под virtual. Сейчас когда запускаю

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

или

python manage.py migrate

отрабатывает как должно. Он находит базу и синхронизирует. Но когда захожу на урл всё время возвращает

> Internal Server Error

В мускуле всё появилось после syncdb, то бишь базу он видит, но что ему не нравится дальше Я просто ума не приложу. С sqlite всё работает. Посоветуйте в какую сторону копать(может где-то логи какие-то глянуть, Я не нашел), пожалуйста.

Comment: Судя по тексту дело до Django не доходит, вам отвечает nginx, поэтому проверьте настройки nginx и посмотрите в его журнал ошибок.

Comment: @idlesign, нет, это та ошибка, которую отдаёт именно django(может python). nginx'овая выглядит иначе + заголовках http её нет. Я сетую на virtualenv, может кто-то что ещё посоветует? п.с. спасибо за ответ.

Comment: А какую ошибку в заголовках вы пытаетесь увидеть? Приведённое вами сообщение уже говорит о том, что сервер ответил статусом 500.  Джанго же в случае ошибки и включенного режима отладки (DEBUG=True) ответит вам не одной фразой, а полной трассировкой стека. Если у вас есть эта трассировка, то опубликуйте её здесь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в логе сервера ничего нет, попробуйте подключить лог исключений:

```
# в файле settings.py создайте новый middleware

import logging    
class ExceptionLoggingMiddleware(object):

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        logging.exception('Исключение, вызванное запросом ' + request.path)
```

И добавьте его к имеющимся:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES +=
('имя_вашего_приложения.settings.ExceptionLoggingMiddleware',)
```

После этого Джанго начнет записывать в лог ошибки, вызванные исключениями.

Comment: Полагаете, что у автора настроены правила LOGGING?

Comment: Просто по умолчанию Джанго не пишет исключения в лог. Я сталкивался с такой проблемой.

Comment: Ну, так я о том и говорю, что пишет или не пишет (а если пишет то куда и что) регламентируется настройкой LOGGING - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/logging/#configuring-logging

Comment: В общем, именно потому, что они не настроены, ошибки 500 могут не попадать в лог.

Comment: не справился Я с выводом ошибок. Таки бросает в nginx 500, Вы были правы.

Answer (score 1):

@iliaznk на счёт вывода логов, то делаю это так.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        },
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue'
        }
    },
    'formatters': {
        'main_formatter': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s:%(name)s: %(message)s '
                      '(%(asctime)s; %(filename)s:%(lineno)d)',
            'datefmt': "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'main_formatter',
        },
        'production_file': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/main.log',
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 5,  # 5 MB
            'backupCount': 7,
            'formatter': 'main_formatter',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        },
        'debug_file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/main_debug.log',
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 5,  # 5 MB
            'backupCount': 7,
            'formatter': 'main_formatter',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
        },
        'null': {
            "class": 'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins', 'console'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['null', ],
        },
        'py.warnings': {
            'handlers': ['null', ],
        },
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'production_file', 'debug_file'],
            'level': "DEBUG",
        },
    }
}
```

где-то на буржском сайте нарыл. Рекомендуемые вами строки добавил, но они ничего не добавили в лог файл. Сейчас туда выводятся только query в базу. С подпиской, что всё гуд.

Решил проблему путем обновления virtualenv'a.

```
easy_install -U distribute #update distribute on your virtualenv
```

Если есть мысли ещё мысли, как вывести правильно логи(500 exception'a) поделитесь) Максимально подробно, если это возможно.

Answer (score 0):

А в settins.py DEBUG=True стоит и потом нигде не перекрывается? Просто тогда обычно приходит более развернутый ответ об ошибке